# Verificación de Webhook de OpenPay

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Tengo que verificar un Webhook que ya creé en el administrador de openpay, sus instrucciones son:

Al terminar la configuración de registro, Openpay enviará mediante POST un mensaje JSON a la URL indicada, conteniendo un objeto de notificación Webhook. Tu servicio deberá guardar el código de verificación de alguna manera, y regresar el estado 200 OK.

Como puedo obtener estos datos que me envía mediante POST utilizando php?

este es el json que me mandara OpenPay:

{
    "type" : "verification",
    "event_date" : "2013-11-22T11:04:49-06:00",
    "verification_code" : "UY1qqrxw"
}

Comment: si guardas en logs lo siguiente que te da? `log_message('debug', json_encode($this->input->post())); log_message('debug', '---'); log_message('debug', json_encode($_REQUEST));` para esto en config tienes que tener 4 en mostrar todos los mensahes

Comment: Hola gracias por tu apoyo, según lo que me mandas debería darme el json que estás enviando, saludos!yo usé file_gets_contents("php://input")

Answer (score 0):

Listo, encontré la respuesta y espero les sirva en su desarrollo.

Para cachar los datos que envía openpay usamos las siguientes lineas:

```
$content    =   file_get_contents("php://input");
$respuesta  =   json_encode($content);
```

Y en respuesta obtendremos el siguiente resultado:

```
"{\"type\":\"verification\",\"event_date\":\"2018-05-30T09:51:59-05:00\",\"verification_code\":\"xxxxxxx\",\"id\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"}"
```

Y con esto ya podemos hacer uso de los datos y verificar el Webhook

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de la respuesta anterior, hay un error en la segunda línea:

```
$content    =   file_get_contents("php://input");
$respuesta  =   json_encode($content);
```

Dado que Openpay devuelve un objeto JSON, se debe de usar json_decode para decodificarlo:

```
$content    =   file_get_contents("php://input");
$respuesta  =   json_decode($content);
```

Comment: realmente he intentado con ambas lineas, decode o encode, pero no puedo leer como tal, hago un var_dump, y la variable esta vacia, podrian ayudarme con el proceso de verificacion?